# vue-reCAPTCHA no funciona

Tags: vue.js, vuex, captcha

Hola estoy utilizando el paquete de vue-reCAPTCHA para insertar una.

Esta capcha es un sub componente por lo que para utilizarlo dentro del sub componente hago lo siguiente.
Este es el script:

```
import VueRecaptcha from 'vue-recaptcha';
export default {
     components: {
         VueRecaptcha
     }
}
```

El componente:

```
<vue-recaptcha ref="recaptcha" 
     @verify="onCaptchaVerified"
     @expired="onCaptchaExpired" size="invisible"
     sitekey="mi llave">

  <v-btn :loading="loader" :disabled="loading" color="secondary" @click="loader = true">
           Accept Terms
  </v-btn>
</vue-recaptcha>
```

Pero me sale el error:

**Error para el propietario del sitio: La clave de sitio no es válida**

me di cuenta que al:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" site-key="mi llave"></div>
```

No aparece en el dom

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que agregar esto en tu `index.html`

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.jsonload=vueRecaptchaApiLoaded&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

En la documentación te lo indica en el [AQUI](https://github.com/DanSnow/vue-recaptcha#usage)